# Using viewDid/WillMoveToSuperview to setup an NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to know which is the best way to setup an NSView.

The only method suitable for this purpose, seems to be `viewDidMoveToSuperview`. 
In this method I can add subviews and in`viewWillMoveToSuperview` I can do geometry operation  on frame etc.

But these are only my suppositions... I can't find a useful documentation that explain where is the better function to perform setup operations.

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't find any documentation on where to set up your `NSView`s is probably that you can set up views, add subviews, etc. in pretty much any method, as long as it is called on the main thread.

For simple apps, `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` of the application delegate is a useful place.

When the app grows, you might want to consider doing this lazily, when a new window is opened or when a view is added.

For normal apps, you won't need to do anything in `viewWillMoveToSuperview`/`viewDidMoveToSuperview`.

Comment: With `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` I can only setup value for Views created at "startup"... but if I need to create new views during the application execution I can't use `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: No, that is why I wrote that any method will do. Just do it when you need it. But make sure it is done on the main thread.